# How does one achieve in R SUBSTRING function like the functionality present in SQL

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (dput at end of post):

```
> d2
  a    b     c
1 1 1111  1111
2 2 2222  2222
3 3    3     3
4 4    4 44444
5 5    5     5
6 6    6 66666
```

what I want to do is print the data frame with substring(b,1,2) and length(c). In SQL it would be something like:

```
select a,substring(b,1,2),length(c) from d2
```

expected output:

```
  a  b c
1 1 11 4
2 2 22 4
3 3  3 1
4 4  4 5
5 5  5 1
6 6  6 5
```

How do I do that in R?

```
> dput(d2)
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), b = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1111", 
"2222", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), c = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1111", 
"2222", "3", "44444", "5", "66666"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some different ways:

**1) sqldf**  Your SQL statement can be run in R like this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a, substr(b,1,2) b, length(c) c from d2")
```

giving:

```
  a  b c
1 1 11 4
2 2 22 4
3 3  3 1
4 4  4 5
5 5  5 1
6 6  6 5
```

**2) transform**  This works without relying on any packages:

```
transform(d2, b = substr(b, 1, 2), c = nchar(as.character(c)))
```

giving:

```
  a  b c
1 1 11 4
2 2 22 4
3 3  3 1
4 4  4 5
5 5  5 1
6 6  6 5
```

**Note 1:** This could also be done in essentially the same way using the dplyr package by replacing `transform` with `mutate` or with the data.table package using `dt <- as.data.table(d2); dt[, c("b", "c") := list(substr(b, 1, 2), nchar(as.character(c)))]`

**Note 2:** Alternatives to `substr(x, 1, 2)` in R are

```
substring(x, 1, 2)

sprintf("%2.2s", x)

sub("(..).*", "\\1", x)

paste(strsplit(x, "")[[1]][1:2], collapse = "")

library(gsubfn);  strapplyc(x, "^..", simplify = TRUE)

library(tcltk); `as.character(tcl('string', 'range', x, 0, 1))
```

.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be using `sub`

```
transform(d2, b = sub('(.{2}).*', '\\1', b), c = nchar(paste(c)))
#  a  b c
#1 1 11 4
#2 2 22 4
#3 3  3 1
#4 4  4 5
#5 5  5 1
#6 6  6 5
```

No packages used...